# What does double slash mean in the file path?

Tags: java

I have a java project which has a property file with the below entry:

```
api_secret_key=target/test-classes//abc-dev.pem
```

What does

> //

in the above path mean?

Comment: Nothing special, it's just redundant

Comment: Absolutely nothing. Usually that someone concatenated `api_secret_key=target/test-classes/` and `/key_v2-768780b283d98-dev.pem`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This has no effect in file paths. The file system will treat them as a single slash.

These paths are all the same:

```
a/b
a//b
a///////b
a/./b
a/../a/b
```